# detect page jump to a specific element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a user preform a certain action, the page reloads and it adds a `#someId` to the URL so the URL will be something like `localhost/panel/mypage.php#someId` and as a default action, the browser will jump to an element with the id of `someId`.

What I would like to do is to catch that using jQuery and then instead of jumping right to the `#someId` element, jump 100px above it and have the ability to add a smooth scrolling.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not use something other than #, which you can read from the URL with jQuery and program the same effect without having to override the browsers default actions?

Comment: @JamesHunt Since the system I'm working with has that default behavior and I would like to keep it unless I really have to due to the impossibility of doing that. However, I had your idea in my mind tbh.

Answer (score 1):

There is this **hashchange** event of the 'window' Document Object that's exactly what you require to catch this behavior. You can use:

1. Javascript solution:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(){
   // smooth scroll code
   });
   ```
2. jQuery solution (v1.8+):

   ```
   jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function(){
   // smooth scroll code
   });
   ```

**Note:** The **hashchange** event gets triggered on url hash change (location.hash) on the same page but not from a different page e.g. going from www.example.com/about.html#first to www.example.com/contact.html#second won't trigger the **hashchange** event.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
var a_hash = window.location.hash;
var offset = $(a_hash).offset();
if(offset.top > 100){
    offset.top = offset.top - 100;
}
var body = $("html, body");
body.animate({scrollTop: offset.top}, '500', 'swing', function() { 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wasn't struggling with how to do the animation part or how to detect the animation but how to remove the browser default behavior. Anyways, thanks for the help.